# Milliseconds value are not getting saved in SQL Server DateTime column

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I need to store a DateTime value which is sent to the Database from a C# application which is using **DateTime.UtcNow**. If I save it to the DateTime column, the milliseconds value are always 000. But while debugging from the application, the milliseconds value is sent from the application to the database.
What am I missing?

Comment: What database service are you using? MSSQL?

Comment: Please show the *exact* specification of the field in the schema.

Comment: @JamesTaylor: I'd assume so, given the tag.

Comment: @James_Taylor always see tags of question.

Comment: @JamesTaylor Yes.. I am using MSSQL

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? ADO.NET? Entity Framework? nHibernate? Please show some code.

Comment: Your C# DateTime.UtcNow has some problem. How to update to database? ToString()?

Comment: @AndersTornblad : I am using dapper framework . As I have bulk data, I am converting the objects into datatable and then sending it to database as a Table Valued parameter.

Comment: @RedDevil can you show your code ?

Comment: I added the **dapper** tag. That will be my only contribution, as I don't know Dapper.

Comment: using (SqlConnection conn = IntelStoreFactory.getInstance())
                {
                    DynamicParameters prm = new DynamicParameters();
                    prm.Add(name: "@LogDetails", value: logDetails.AsTableValuedParameter("LogDetails"));
                   
                    conn.Open();
                    conn.Query(sql: Constants.PROC_ADD_CYCLE_COUNT_LOG_DETAILS, param: prm, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                    conn.Close();
                }

Comment: @RedDevil added the code to your question. Next time do not use comments to show your code

Comment: You should use `DATETIME2(3)` instead - that **IS** accurate to the millisecond! Available in SQL Server **2008** and newer

Comment: @Steve : Thank you so much..

Comment: @marc_s : I tried that, but no luck :(

Comment: Could you show how do you have coded the Type that represent the Table Valued Parameter in your database?

Comment: For the record: dapper does **nothing whatsoever** to the value - it just sets it as the `.Value`. I strongly suspect that this is database level rounding, which is entirely exected

Comment: btw; do you know that you don't need `DynamicParameters` here? in the plain-text command scenario you can just use `new { LogDetails = logDetails.AsTableValuedParameter("LogDetails") }` as the parameter; and in *your* case (a stored procedure), you could just use `new {LogDetails = logDetails }` - heck, if the server isn't configured to be case sensitive you could just use `new { logDetails }`. And for extra credit: *you don't need to call `Open()` and `Close()`*
 - dapper **does that for you** (if it detects a non-open connection)

Comment: I concur with @MarcGravell, tried to make a table with datetime type and passed a Table Valued Parameter with UtcNow set. There is no loss of milliseconds. (with the range of precision expected by the datetime type) so the error is somewhere in your code. I ask again How did you code the T-SQL type that represent the Table Valued Parameter passed? How do you check the content of the table? Looking at it with SSMS shows the milliseconds part with no problem (also added a Thread.Delay to get different values)

Answer (score 3):

It *might* happen because [`datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) column rounds milliseconds part. From documentation;

> Accuracy
>
> Rounded to increments of `.000`, `.003`, or `.007` seconds

Since you *didn't* show us how often you store your `UtcNow` value (I assume you store it as a `DateTime`, not it's string representation because parameterless `ToString` and other standard formats does not generates millisecond part *usually*), this may happen but if you do it in short time intervals, it would be really weird always rounding to `000` as milliseconds part. But of course, we *can't* know that, yet.

On the other hand, [`datetime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) type does not do any rounding. And it's accuracy is 100 nanoseconds.

> Accuracy
>
> 100 nanoseconds

Answer (score 3):

Here's no pleasant way to use `Datetime` because

> SQL Server only stores time to approximately 1/300th of a second.
>   These always fall on the 0, 3 and 7 milliseconds

SQL Server 2008 has much more precision available. The `datetime2` datatype will accurately store values like this: `2008-12-19 09:31:38.5670514`

See [reference documentation](http://rwgarrison.com/PASS/TimeDateTime2/)

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like something/someone is doing a default-ToString instead of using ToString with the proper ISO-standard format.

Proper ISO-format for date with time is

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff
```

while date-only ISO-format is

```
yyyyMMdd
```

You can check:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.DateTime cur = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
    string strDefault = cur.ToString();
    string str  = cur.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    System.Console.WriteLine(str);
    System.Console.WriteLine(strDefault);
}
```

This outputs

> 2016-03-03T08:31:27.324
>   03.03.2016 08:31:27

You might also want to use the HEX-format, as this enhances precision, or at least preserves a value that already was in SQL-Server. If you don't use hex-representation, you can get a 23:59:59.997 value from SQL-server and resave, and you'll have 00:00:00 with day+1. Using the hex-format preserves .997, while saving an ISO-string will yield day+1.

```
public static string GetTimeAsHex(System.DateTime dt)
{
    System.DateTime zero = new System.DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
    System.TimeSpan ts = dt - zero;
    System.TimeSpan ms = ts.Subtract(new System.TimeSpan(ts.Days, 0, 0, 0));

    double x = System.Math.Floor(ms.TotalMilliseconds / 3.3333333333);
    string hex = "0x" + ts.Days.ToString("X8") + System.Convert.ToInt32(x).ToString("X8");

    return hex;
}
```

Anyway, as others have already told you, SQL-server datetime is only precise to within a 4 ms error margin. This is why you should use datetime2, as it fixes many issues (bugs/"features") in datetime, including insufficient precision in the milliseconds range.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your `INSERT` statement as a `string`, try specifying the output of milliseconds in the string conversion

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: But of  course, inserting `DateTime` as their string representation is mostly bad idea.

Comment: Specifically it would have horrendous performance impact when you came to sort based on time (or any other manipulation).

Comment: I agree, this isn't the best way to do it.

Comment: "If you are building your INSERT statement as a string" - then you're already making a huge ton of mistakes